# Give a example of a sequence of continuous functions which do not form a Cauchy sequence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

> As an example that not every Cauchy sequence in $(M,d)$ is converging in $M$ the following examples are given:
>
> - Consider $(\mathbb{Q},d_{\text{eucl}})$ and a sequence $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}\to \pi$. Which is a Cauchy sequence (as $d_\text{eucl}(q_1,q_2)\to 0)$ but the sequence does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.
> - A second example is given. Consider:
>   $$\left(\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}), d_1\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad d_1(f,g) = \int_0^1 |f-g|$$  Where $f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ mean $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ continous.

I need to find a counterexample in this last metric space. I know I need to search for a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ where $d_1(f_a,f_b)\to 0$ but the limit shouldn't live in that space of functions. How can I find this?

#### Note

Below the problem is written: 'in $\left(\mathcal{L}^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}), d_1\right)$ every Cauchy sequence will be converging.'

Where $\mathcal{L}^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is the space of Lesbeque integrable functions. I guess I should construct a sequence of functions wich converges to a function which is Lesbeque integrale, but not continous. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions $f_n(x)$ where they take on value $0$ for $x< \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}$, $1$ for $x > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$ and grow linearly from $0$ to $1$ on $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n} < x  < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$.

Then, $d(f_n, f_m) \leq 4 \frac{1}{n}$ for $n <m$ (since each $f_n$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$ and the two functions only differ on $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n} < x  < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$). So, the sequence is Cauchy.

However, the limit of $f_n$ with respect to this would be $0$ for $x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ for $x > \frac{1}{2}$, which is not continuous.

Comment: Awesome construction. But I ponder the classical question *"how can I find such a construction myself?"*

Comment: Well, its a "standard fact" that continuous functions are dense in $L^1([0,1])$. So you can take any function in $L^1$ which is not continuous and take a sequence of continuous functions to approximate it. Also, piecewise linear or piecewise constant and then doing a bit of smoothing to make continuous/differentiable/whatever is a pretty standard trick.